# is there any way to force open a link in Safari even user's default browser isn't Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios14

this is for iOS 14 only, which supports changing default behavior. Right now only Safari supports webRTC now and we have to redirect to Safari for video calls.

Comment: This is related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950609/launch-safari-from-app-on-ios-14-when-safari-is-not-the-default-browser-using-th